# Select "enabled" rows plus the currently selected rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of users. Each user has an enabled flag that is either 1 or 0.

Say I want to have a select box with all enabled users, that's easy enough to do. My trouble comes down the road when a user is **editing** a form and it pulls up the **currently** enabled users, but the currently selected user **is not** an enabled user.

Normally my query would be something like

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name from users WHERE enabled = 1
```

However, if this is an edit form, and the currently selected user isn't enabled anymore and the user submits the form, I will lose the currently selected user.

What would be the best way to handle this? The only way I can think to do it is to create a join in the query that also gets the currently enabled user but I'm wondering if there is a better way. Mainly because some of our forms have this user field in  5 or 6 places on a page and I would have to have to make 5 or 6 different queries just so that I could get the current user.

Comment: can you show an example, even if just an HTML mockup

Comment: What do you mean by "*the currently selected user isn't an enabled user*"?  If the select box only contains enabled users, how can a disabled user currently be selected?

Comment: The user was selected a year ago. Since then, the user has become a disabled user (say they don't work at the company anymore).

Comment: I think I get what you are saying.  When you say that building `a select box with all enabled users, that's east enough to do.` you were talking statically creating it in HTML and you want to create that dynamically with a database selection, but not reproduce that query X times through the form...

Comment: No Dave, I know how to do that. The issue is with an edit form. The edit form would bring up all enabled users. What if the user was enabled a year ago but isn't enabled now. That user would not show up in the select box anymore.

Comment: I don't understand. How can a selected user be disabled if you display only enabled users on that form? Give code, or screenshots, or things that make us get your point..

Comment: Me too do not understand. If You have user that was enabled but now is not, and You open an edit form, this user logically isn't populated into the select box - as he is disabled. So I cannot imagine how he could be `currently selected`. It smells like somebody selected that user a year ago while he was enabled, then he become disabled (while still selected in some form - great session!) and now (when he is disabled) somebody hits SAVE on that form. Please, provide more details on the logics of Your problem, thanks!

Comment: Post more code then (or even pseudo code), because no one can understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: shadyyyx, yes you are correct. Say your form contains data for a sales person for a lead. You select who the salesperson is. Then a year later, you're editing that same lead with that salesperson but he is now a disabled user. That is the issue I am running into. Dave, people do seems to understand because there have been solutions posted below. I am just waiting to make sure a better solution doesn't come up.

Comment: so add what user113215 provided to Pitchinnate's code `SELECT first_name,last_name from users WHERE enabled=1 or user_id=$current_user` replacing `$current_user` with however you identify the owner of the record you are viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally understand the problem. The easiest way I could approach this is by loading ALL users but only filter them when you're building the drop-down.

The drop-down condition would become something like:

```
if ($user['enabled'] || $user['id'] == $lead['admin']) { ... }
```

You can do the same thing with a `JOIN` condition in SQL, but that would require more work if multiple roles are present on the form.

Whether or not loading ALL users is a problem, I can't tell :)

Comment: I like this answer the most. It doesn't require me to do two queries (1 to find the current user and 1 to get all the users). This is especially helpful in my case because I am using the same query 5 times on a page that can have 5 different users. With my current situation, loading all the users is not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you can get the ID of the selected user before you generate the dropdown list, you only need to add an `OR` clause to your query.

> SELECT first_name, last_name from users WHERE enabled = 1 **OR user_id = ?**

This will guarantee the previously selected user appears in the list. It's safe to add the `OR` clause in all cases (whether or not the selected user is enabled).

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that only gets called if the current user isn't enabled.

```
$result=your_database_version('select username from users where enabled=1');
$found = false;
user_options = '';
while($row=your_db_fetch_array($result)){
    $selected = '';
    if($current_user == $row['user']) {
        $found = true;
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    $user_options.="<option value='{$row['user']}' $selected>{$row['user']}</option>";
}
if(!$found) {
    $user_options .= add_current_user($current_user);
}

function add_current_user($current_user) {
    //Get info from database for $current_user
    $row=your_db_fetch_array($result)
    return "<option value='{$row['user']}' selected>{$row['user']}</option>";
}
```

Comment: user113215's answer is better if you can modify the original queries. My answer is only if you can't modify or don't want to modify them for some reason.